# How to mask out all non-letter characters from a scrambled vector of letters and numbers in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab and have a homework problem where I'm given a scrambled character vector and have to mask out all non-letter characters. I have to write a script that can take any scrambled vector so I do not know the location of the numbers.

I've tried to remove the numbers from the vector, but am unsure how to successfully do it.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be expected to use [`isletter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isletter.html). For example:

```
str = 'abcde1234xyz';
str(~isletter(str)) = '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

regexp is a function you may want to know. It finds regular expressions in a string, including numbers. Here is an example:

```
str = 'ajY34hS21e4R5f';
% find numbers location
iNum = regexp(str,'[0-9]');
% replace numbers with spaces
strNoNum = regexprep(str,'[0-9]',' ');
```